# jquery match multiple data groups (only if they are all true)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data groups on elements

```
data-foo
data-bar
```

I'd like to have a jquery selector that selects items where foo and bar BOTH match, e.g.

```
$("[data-foo='blah'],[data-bar='quax']")
```

would select the elements where `data-foo = 'blah'` and `data-bar='quax'`

It seems right now I'm getting results where `data-foo=blah` OR `data-bar=quax`. I need this to be `data-foo=blah` AND `data-bar=quax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take out the comma. In essence, that is an OR selector. Without the comma, it looks for both.

```js
console.log($("[data-foo='blah'],[data-bar='quax']").length) // 3 = not what you want 
console.log($("[data-foo='blah'][data-bar='quax']").length) // 1 = what you want
console.log($("[data-foo='blah'][data-bar='quax']").html()) // Just to make sure its the right one
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-foo="blah" data-bar="quax">Both</div>
<div data-foo="blah">Foo</div>
<div data-bar="quax">Bar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("[data-foo='blah']").filter("[data-bar='quax']")
```

However, this isn't terribly efficient, compared to [@jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219661/jamiec)'s answer which uses a single selector.